# Change a icon fonts when clicking on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, icons, icon-fonts

This is my html:

```
<div class="menu">
  <span aria-hidden="true" class="btn" data-icon="&#128275;"></span>
</div>
```

And when I click on span tag I would like data-icon will change: `data-icon="&#128275;`

```
$icon = $(event.currentTarget)
if $icon.attr('data-icon') == '&#128275;'
      $icon.attr('data-icon', "&#128274;")
    else
      $icon.attr('data-icon', "&#128275;")
```

But although 'data-icon' changed correctly, the screen displays the string `&#128275;` instead the icon.

Comment: What is rendering `data-icon` for you?

Comment: Any hint on which framework you are using?

Comment: It is only an attribute with the code of the font. I don't use any framework. Reference: http://css-tricks.com/examples/IconFont/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
$.parseHTML("&#128274;")[0].data
```

So, the complete code:

```
$icon = $(event.currentTarget)
if $icon.attr('data-icon') == $.parseHTML("&#128274;")[0].data
      $icon.attr('data-icon', $.parseHTML("&#128275;")[0].data)
    else
      $icon.attr('data-icon', $.parseHTML("&#128274;")[0].data)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="menu">
  <span aria-hidden="true" class="btn" data-icon="&#128275;" id="yourspan"></span>
</div>
```

Using the id of your span

```
$("#yourspan").on('click',function(){
  if($("#yourspan").attr('data-icon')=='&#128275;'){
    $("#yourspan").attr('data-icon','&#128274;');
  }
  else{
    $("#yourspan").attr('data-icon','&#128275;')
  }
});
```

Comment: Thats not work. In addition 'data-icon' works fine with $icon.attr('data-icon', "&#128275;"). Same behaviour in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Improving answer by Deepu, check this

```
$('body').on('click', '#yourspan', function(){
  if($(this).attr('data-icon')=='&#128275;'){
    $(this).attr('data-icon','&#128274;');
  }
  else{
    $(this).attr('data-icon','&#128275;');
  }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It have to be something about html entities and how encode it in the assignation I think.